# How do I set input date variable to end of day to the minute?

Tags: sql, t-sql

My stored procedure passes a mm/dd/yyyy date as an input. But I need the input date to round up to 23:59:59

This is my current variable

```
DECLARE @AsOfDate VARCHAR(12)    
SET @AsOfDate = '5/13/2019'
```

I tried setting my variable

```
DECLARE @Time TIME = '23:59:59.999'
```

My variable passed misses records for that day that occur on the minute scale afterward.

Comment: You show a variable but dont show us the query.  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That could be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you have something like `some_date BETWEEN @some_other_variable AND @the_variable_in_question` use `some_date >= @some_other_variable AND some_date < dateadd(day, 1, @the_variable_in_question)`. And in no case should the date be in a string variable. There's the `date` data type for dates.

Comment: Do you need minute, as the title says, or second as 23:59:59 implies? The answer appears to be neither as you are missing records from the last minute of the day. As others have noted, use `<` midnight to capture all of the rows up to, but not including. the next date.

Answer (score 0):

> My variable passed misses records for that day that occur on the
>   minute scale afterward.

This is a common problem when dealing with date and datetime data types. Your procedure is bring the dates in as VARCHAR(12) then your query is converting those values into the datatype, `DATETIME`. Consider this query:

```
DECLARE @startDate VARCHAR(12) = '5/1/2019', @endDate VARCHAR(12) = '5/3/2019';
SELECT  [@startDate] = CAST(@startDate AS DATETIME), [@endDate] = CAST(@endDate AS DATETIME);
```

**Returns:**

```
@startDate              @endDate
----------------------- -----------------------
2019-05-01 00:00:00.000 2019-05-03 00:00:00.000
```

In this situation, a query that returns records between @startDate and @endDate will not return anything from 5/3/2019 (unless it happened at exactly 2019-05-03 00:00:00.000). Now look at the query below. There are three records, one on 5/1, 5/2 and 5/3:

```
DECLARE @sales TABLE (saleDate DATETIME);
INSERT @sales(saleDate) VALUES ('2019-05-01 13:50:59.222'),('2019-05-02 03:50:22.255'),('2019-05-03 10:31:12.228');

DECLARE @startDate VARCHAR(12) = '5/1/2019', @endDate VARCHAR(12) = '5/3/2019';

SELECT *
FROM @sales AS s 
WHERE s.saleDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate;
```

... It does not include records for 5/3

```
saleDate
-----------------------
2019-05-01 13:50:59.223
2019-05-02 03:50:22.257
```

> I need the input date to round up to 23:59:59

You could do this:

```
DECLARE @AsOfDate VARCHAR(12) = '5/3/2019' ;

SELECT DATEADD(MS,-2,DATEADD(DAY,1,CAST(@AsOfDate AS DATETIME)));
```

Which returns `2019-05-03 23:59:59.997`; you would use it in your query like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM @sales AS s 
WHERE s.saleDate BETWEEN @startDate AND DATEADD(MS,-2,DATEADD(DAY,1,CAST(@endDate AS DATETIME)));
```

**But this is not *really* what you want.** This will give you what you need and it's cleaner:

```
SELECT *
FROM @sales AS s 
WHERE s.saleDate BETWEEN @startDate AND DATEADD(DAY,1,@endDate);
```

Here I'm just adding a day to the @endDate which will solve your problem.